# gson deserialize correctly an object but not its internal

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this class:

```
public class Campaign 
{

String Campaign_ID;
String Campaign_Description;
String startQuestion;
ArrayList Question_Array;
ArrayList workflow;

public Campaign(String ID, String description, String start, ArrayList quesArray, ArrayList workflow)
{
    this.Campaign_ID = ID;
    this.Campaign_Description = description;
    this.startQuestion = start;
    this.Question_Array = quesArray;
    this.workflow = workflow;
}

public String getID() {return this.Campaign_ID;}
public String getDescription() {return this.Campaign_Description;}
public String getStartQuestion() {return this.startQuestion;}
public ArrayList getQuestionArray() {return this.Question_Array;}
public ArrayList getWorkflow() {return this.workflow;}

public Base_Question getQuestionByID(String ID){
    Base_Question result = null;
    for (int i=0;i<Question_Array.size();i++)
    {
        if (    ((Base_Question) Question_Array.get(i)).getQuestionID().equals(ID) ) 
            result = (Base_Question) Question_Array.get(i);
    }       
    return result;      
}

}
```

The ArrayList `Question_Array` contains a list of instances from other classes.
Then I initialize an instance of Campaign:

```
Campaign campaign = new Campaign("Cam999","description blabla","Q001",list, workflow);
```

Then I serialize this instance into text:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();     
String text = gson.toJson(campaign);
```

To get back the instance of Campaign class, I use:

```
Campaign campaign2 = gson.fromJson(text, Campaign.class);
```

I can print things from campaign2 correctly, like `campaign2.getID()` returns Cam999. But the problem is the ArrayList inside campaign2.
`campaign2.getQuestionArray().get(index).getClass()` prints **com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap**, not my custom class.

My whole source code is here https://github.com/khoiboo/Class_Hierarchy

How to solve this problem. I appreciate your help so much

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: My whole project is here: https://github.com/khoiboo/Class_Hierarchy

Comment: Maybe take a look to [gson docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples). Hope it helps.